# how to parse parameter value passed to make file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile which takes a TYPE parameter and runs a test file using that name. Otherwise it takes all the test files.

```
ifneq (,$(TYPE))
TEST_SRCS := $(wildcard test/$(TYPE)Test.cpp)
else
TEST_SRCS := $(wildcard test/*Test.cpp)
endif

print:
    echo $(TEST_SRCS)
```

This works fine If I execute like,

```
make TYPE=Add
```

But Now I want to give more than one value to **TYPE** So that it should take both AddTest.cpp and SubtractTest.cpp

e.g.

```
make TYPE=Add,Subtract
```

I have tried `$(foreach var,$(TYPE), TEST_FILES += var)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make isn't good at this kind of manipulation, but you can break a comma-separated list into a space-separated list like this:

```
COMMA = ,
TYPE_LIST = $(subst $(COMMA), ,$(TYPE))
```

Then you can apply your wildcard logic like this:

```
FILE_LIST = $(patsubst %,test/%Test.cpp,$(TYPE_LIST))
TEST_SRCS := $(wildcard $(FILE_LIST))
```

Comment: Alternatively, just use `make TYPE='Add Subtract'` on the command line in the first place and avoid needing `COMMA` and the `subst` that goes along with it.